# Null Rate of all columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table (People) with these columns

```
Gender
Name
Address
Employment
Education
```

I want a query that will output the percent null rate for all columns while grouping by [Gender] column.

The table I am using has 60 columns so I do not want to hard code the columns. I am using the above just as an example.

I am expecting output similar to this. The figures are percent null rate

| Gender | Name | Address | Employment | Education |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Male | 0.2365 | 0.5642 | 0.3652 | 0.1563 |
| Female | 0.5263 | 0.3265 | 0.5214 | 0.1563 |

Comment: _"the table i am using has 60 columns so do not hard code the columns."_ - What do you mean by this? (If you're asking for a Dynamic SQL solution, I'll tell you I think that's a bad idea, and specifying a column-name in a query is not "hard coding" it - it's simply how SQL works.

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: "I do not want to hard code the columns"  Then you can't SELECT since it requires you to specify column names.

Answer (score 1):

Can use the [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/columns-transact-sql) table to get the columns, then from there it is just a matter of constructing your dynamic query.

```
DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(100) = 'People'
DECLARE @GroupColumn VARCHAR(100) = 'Gender'

DECLARE @DynamicSelect VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @DynamicSelect =
    'SELECT ' + @GroupColumn + ', ' + 
    STRING_AGG(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), 'AVG(CASE WHEN [' + COLUMN_NAME +'] IS NULL THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END) AS ' + COLUMN_NAME), ', ') + 
    ' FROM ' + @TableName + ' GROUP BY ' + @GroupColumn
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName AND COLUMN_NAME <> @GroupColumn

EXEC(@DynamicSelect)
```

This constructs and executes a query similar to this:

```
SELECT
    Gender,
    AVG(CASE WHEN [Name] IS NULL THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END) AS Name,
    AVG(CASE WHEN [Address] IS NULL THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END) AS Address,
    -- etc
FROM People
GROUP BY Gender
```

Comment: when i run your code it run successfully without any out put. This is what i am getting:  Commands completed successfully completion time: and a time stamp

Comment: seems like that happens when the table name is incorrect, does the table name match your actual table?